# Pick equal number of examples from each category that fits within the context length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Pick all lines with the smallest `word_count` from a CSV file in a round-robin fashion based on `type` (so that all `types` are present as much as possible) that fit within the context length.

`def get_line_from_input_csv_with_in_context_length(input_file, context_length):`

- `context_length = 2001`

I have a CSV file containing the following fields:

```
line_no,type,word_count
1,assertEquals,704
2,assertThat,303
3,assertNotNull,159
4,assertThat,348
5,assertFalse,186
6,assertArrayEquals,699
7,assertEquals,119
8,assertTrue,314
9,assertEquals,552
10,assertSame,151
11,assertEquals,110
12,assertEquals,210
13,assertTrue,807
14,assertTrue,1231
15,assertEquals,541
16,assertEquals,1435
17,assertEquals,305
18,assertEquals,134
19,assertArrayEquals,641
20,assertEquals,800
21,assertEquals,522
22,assertEquals,150
23,assertThat,608
24,assertArrayEquals,280
25,assertEquals,245
26,assertEquals,364
27,assertEquals,637
28,assertEquals,615
29,assertThat,362
30,assertTrue,1468
```

Here expected output:

```
assertEquals, line_no= 110, 119, 134, 245
assertThat, line_no= 303
assertNotNull, line_no= 159
assertFalse,  line_no= 186
assertArrayEquals, line_no= 280
assertSame, line_no= 151
assertTrue, line_no=314
```

I know how to do it in a brute force way i.e.:

- Grouping the input file based on `type` and putting it into a list of a multi-dictionary.
- Then, sort each entry of that multi-dictonary i.e. for each type based on `word_count` and put that in a list.
- Now iterate `list of list` and pick the smallest until I hit the `context_length`.

But I am sure there is a more pythonic way to achieve this. Can anyone suggest me any pointers?

Comment: And what rule do you need?

Comment: As example:`[["a",11],["b",31],["a",31]]`,`context_length = 42`. What to choose:"b" or "a"?

Comment: It needs to be as equitable as possible to get equal representation. But it is not always possible to pick all `types` equally because of context length.Here it should be `[["a",11],["b",31]]` as `a` at least has one example. I am finding this logic quite hard to implement.

Comment: Not sure what your priority is.  Why not "assertEquals, line_no= 110, 119
assertThat, line_no= 303, 348"?  Why do you want 4 assertEqual entries and 1 assertThat as opposed to 2 assertEqual and 2 assertThat?  Wouldn't that fit better with round robin allocation?

Comment: @TroyD ops. Yes - you are right - it is a bug in the output that I have added. It should show 2 `assertThat` instead of choosing `4` assertEquals.

Comment: @Exploring, And why?

Comment: Another example:`[["a",11],["b",31],["a",31],["b",11]]`,`context_length = 53`. What to choose:"b" or "a"?

Comment: @George here: `a, 11` and `b,11` must be present. And then either of the `a, 31` or `b,31` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas, we can group everything by type and then rank all the elements in each group according to word count.  Then we can sort all these by rank and word_count to get them into the proper order.  Once they are sorted, we do a cumsum() to get the running total to compare against context_length.  And finally do another group by to get it listed out by type:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(csv_io, index_col=0)
context_length = 2001

df['rank'] = df.groupby("type")['word_count'].rank(method="first", ascending=True)
df = df.sort_values(['rank', 'word_count'])
df['word_count_cumsum'] = df['word_count'].cumsum()

df = df[df['word_count_cumsum'] < context_length]

types_list = df.groupby('type')['word_count'].apply(list)

print(types_list)
```

Output looks like:

```
type
assertArrayEquals         [280]
assertEquals         [110, 119]
assertFalse               [186]
assertNotNull             [159]
assertSame                [151]
assertThat           [303, 348]
assertTrue                [314]
Name: word_count, dtype: object
```

Comment: Still looking into your code. But this is incredible. I wrote ~500 lines of code to do this, which is still buggy :-(

Comment: Cool, glad it helps :)  Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: sort by rank should be enough `df.sort_values(['rank']`. Isnt it?

Comment: It'll be almost the same, but it may alter which get selected at the end of the algorithm, as it might prioritize some elements that have the same rank but a higher word count.  For example, if you change context_length = 1860, you'll get a different answer if you have or don't have 'word_count' in your sort.

Answer (score 0):

As example, you can use this:

1. Read data from CSV file and sort it by **`word_count`**,
   and next group by **`type`**.
2. Pick the first element based on **`var_count`**, while you can pick it:

   ```py
   var_count = [[i,0,csv_data[i]] for i in type]
   var_count = sorted(var_count,key = lambda i:i[2][i[1]])
   while cnt < context_length:
       i = var_count[0]
       cur_group = i[0]#Current Group
       cur_len = i[2][i[1]]#Current Length
       var_count[0][1] += 1
       #Paste your code ONLY here
       var_count = sorted(var_count,key = lambda i:i[2][i[1]])
   ```